# Take user input into a matrix of unknown size until -1 is entered

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

So I need to read in an integer matrix from standard input from the user. The matrix will be specified with spaces between the columns and with each row on a new line. The input is terminated with a -1.

**Input**

```
3 9 7 1
2 4 8 6
3 7 9 2
-1
```

I know that 2D arrays cannot be used since the dimension of the matrix is unknown. I've read up about 2d arraylists but I'm unsure on how to store or read that info from the user.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`  of `integers`
for example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
```

Example Code:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();


private void buildMatrix() {
    String rows [] = new String[10];
    for(String eachRow: rows) {
        matrix.add(processRow(eachRow));    
    }
}

public ArrayList<Integer> processRow(String row) {
    ArrayList<Integer> rowInts = new ArrayList<>();
    if (null != row && row.contains(" ")) {
        String numbers[] = row.split(" ");
        for (String number : numbers) {
            try {
                int numberAsInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
                rowInts.add(numberAsInt);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return rowInts;
}
```

Comment: Okay i do get that part. But then how will store or get that information from the user. Like I'm unsure how my while loop should look like

Comment: Added more code, hope it helps

Comment: it did help abit with all the code. But in line 3 are you not still giving a specified amount of rows in that array rather then letting the user decide on it?

Comment: Yes, I am taking specified amount of rows, but you can take it from user and pass it

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a real drag to repeatedly enter data by hand. Might want to read in from a file instead.

```
  /**
   * Load a set of loot items into loot table from a CSV file
   * @param fileName expected CSV format: | String name | int tries |
   * @throws NumberFormatException if 2nd column isn't an integer
   * @throws FileNotFoundException if can't find the CSV file
   * @throws IOException other I/O & storage problems
   */
  public void load(String fileName){  
    try {
      BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
      String lineItem;

      while ((lineItem = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] lootDetails = lineItem.split(",");

        lootRecord record = new lootRecord();
        record.name       = lootDetails[0];
        record.tries      = Integer.valueOf(lootDetails[1]);

        table.add(record);
    }
    fileReader.close();
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid String: Integer count of tries expected");
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} // load
```

Comment: I've read up and found methods on how to read from a file. However, this does not help me as i need to read from user input until -1 is entered.